# What is the best Struts2 compliant LGPL Javascript UI components library out there?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, user-interface, struts2

We currently have an application built with Struts 1.2. We are currently migrating it to Struts2 and are looking for a nice LGPL library of UI web components **that will still exists within the next couple of years** :

- The cream of the cream would have been **ExtJS**, but the GPL license (and its subtle move from LGPL to GPL) is a No-Go.
- We've then taken at the LGPL fork (**GWT-Ext**), but it seems that its future is not uncertain as part of the community want to have it evolve with ExtJS (and not stick with 2.0.2...) hence becoming GPL also.
- We've taken a look at **Dojo**, but we are not sure that it is mature enough.
- We would have loved to use **jQueryUI**, but there is a big lack of UI components compared to other frameworks.
- **Qooxdoo** looks amazing, but has no community.
- We've also taken a look at **YUI**, and it seems promising... But again, there are doubts.

What is your advice on the question?

Answer (score 1):

We are starting a new Struts2 project with jQuery UI and jQuery tools (http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html).  It's got enough stuff for us, but may not provide everything you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for the answer, though jQueryUI/jQueryTools don't provide enough widgets for our project. A good grid component is a must-have.

Comment: Yeah, no grid kinda sucks.  We used Ext on our previous project (bought a license).  Have you seen the jQuery Grid Plugin? http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: We have, but what worries me is that most jQuery components are created by individual users and not by jQuery's designers. The official jQueryUI only has so few components... Who knows how long user components will be supported, or if they will be compatible with jQuery in the future...